# Issue with UTF-8 data request on production

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, utf-8

I had a requirement from client to support saving UTF-8 data entered by users(Chinese, japanese etc) into our application database and display them as it is.
For this i changed my DB character set and updated my JDBC connection string to support UTF-8 data processing. After this setup i was successfully able to store chinese language in my database and show it in my application UI as it is.

But on my production server, i am getting issues with this. I investigated this on production system and found out that the characters that i enter in my production application UI, say for example **"你叫什么名字"** got converted to **"æ?¨å¤?ã ®ã?³ã?³ã?µã?¼ã??ã ¯æ??é«?ã §ã ?ã ?ã??"** when my production application received the request. Though when i run the same thing on my local machine, i receive the characters as it is, i.e if i enter **"你叫什么名字"** in ui, i get **"你叫什么名字"** in request data as well on my home system.

The application in my production is deployed on tomcat7 and centos OS, whereas my local machine(development environment) is windows 7, tomcat 7.

Is this caused by some issue in tomcat configuration?or is it some setting in OS?

Please suggest what might be wrong in this?

Comment: Have you checked the URIEncoding setting for Tomcat7 in server.xml? It should be set to UTF-8.

Comment: You indeed appear to have an encoding problem.  You must always remember that every character sequence is an *interpretation* of an underlying byte sequence according to a particular encoding scheme.  There have been many such encoding schemes, and there are still several in common use.  If one component or machine in a processing chain interprets a byte sequence according to a different encoding than the previous one used to encode it, then you may get garbage.  But maybe not: some characters, especially the first 128 of Unicode, are encoded the same way by many encodings.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore : Your suggestion worked like a charm :) . Finally the issue is resolved and i am getting the character input as expected in UTF-8. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check that `server.xml` for Tomcat7 has `URIEncoding` set to `UTF-8`. That should fix the issue.